# Wordpress wp_create_user password doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, hash, passwords

This problem seems to be old enough, I've searched over the internet for possible solutions but nothing seems to conclude in a successful way to do it.

Here is what I got:

In the theme I have a custom form which postos username, password and email to a script using the following function:

```
function createSubscriberUser($username, $email, $password) {
        $user_id = username_exists( $username );
        if ( !$user_id and email_exists($email) == false ) {
            $user_id = wp_create_user( $username, $password, $email );
        } else {
            $hash = __('User already exists.  Password inherited.');
        }
    }
```

This works great! the user is succesfully created as a subscriber. However When I try to login the newly created user using wp-login.php, I always get that credentials are invalid.

So I used the following snippet just to see what was going on:

```
$username = $_POST['user'];
                $pass = $_POST['pass'];
                $user = get_user_by( 'login', $username );
                if ( $user && wp_check_password( $pass, $user->data->user_pass, $user->ID) )
                   echo " That's it";
                else
                   echo " Nope";
```

I'm always getting a "Nope"... but if I use a user created from the dashboard, I get the "That's it" message. So my wild guess is that the hashes being generated by wp_create_user are always different from the ones generated by wp_check_password when passing a plain text password as input from the user.

Is there a way to get the same hash? to login from wp-login.php and programmatically as well?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: In the [wp_create_user()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user) example they use wp_generate_password() to create a password.  Maybe see what wp_generate_password() returns and that may help you debug further.

Comment: the wp_generate_password creates a random string of n length, this is plain text, so the wp_create_user still hash it even if its random.

Comment: it would probably be good to show the output of the variables involved?

Comment: I have the same issue but still not get any answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are supplying the 'plain text' password to the `wp_create_user` function. I had faced the same issue. I was hashing the password and using it in the `wp_create_user`.

`wp_create_user` is much like a wrapper function for `wp_insert_user`. See the below source code:

```
function wp_create_user($username, $password, $email = '') {
   $user_login = wp_slash( $username );
   $user_email = wp_slash( $email    );
   $user_pass = $password;

   $userdata = compact('user_login', 'user_email', 'user_pass');
   return wp_insert_user($userdata);
}
```

`wp_insert_user` will generate its own md5 hash.

Alternatively you can directly call the `wp_insert_user` like this:

```
$user_login = wp_slash( $user_name );
$user_email = wp_slash( $user_email    );
$user_pass = $user_password;

$userdata = compact('user_login', 'user_email', 'user_pass');
$user_id = wp_insert_user($userdata);
```

Answer (score 0):

Prev answer from 2015... I had the similar issue. Upon creating a user,  "password" worked fine, but not on updating user.

The reason is that I was tempted to use `wp_insert_user()` that can also update user data

BUT here is the catch: upon update you need to provide **hashed password** and NOT plain text as in initial creation case. Its not well docmented, but you can [see it in the code](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_user/)

There are two ways to go ON UPADTING an exiting user:

1. Do not update password (i.e. remove it from arguments, or leave it empty), let the user have full control over his/hers password.
2. If you wish to modify existing user password, use: `wp_hash_password('plain-text-pass')`